# Как формировать в цикле строки с разным количеством элементов?

Tags: вёрстка, php, циклы

Здравствуйте! Меня всегда ставят в тупик задачи, когда нужно, выводя в цикле элементы массива, формировать строки с разным количеством элементов. Например, у меня есть массив $arResult["ITEMS"] c 6 товарами. Мне нужно выводить эти товары на экран сначала по 2 элемента в строке, затем - по одному:

```
<div class="collection_page_content_row">
тут 2 элемента
</div>
<div class="collection_page_content_row collection_item collection_item">
тут 1 элемент
</div>
```

и так далее. Естественно, если элементы заканчиваются, нужно корректно закрыть div. Не пойму, как условия граматно составить на открытие и закрытие div-строк. Вёрстка изменениям не подлежит, там у парных и одиночных элементов разные стили и css классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); #собственно массив
$len = count($a); # запомним размер массива
$div = 3; # по сколько разбивать
print "<div>\n"; # первый div
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    print $a[$i]."\n"; # собственно вывод
    if (($i + 1) % $div == 0 and $i != $len) { 
        print "</div>\n<div>\n"; # разделитель
    }
}
print "</div>\n"; # последний div

?>
```

вариант номер два, как по мне, то он менее эффективный, но легче к модификации

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); #собственно массив
$len = count($a); # запомним размер массива
$div = 3; # по сколько разбивать

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i+=$div) {
    $sr = array_slice($a, $i, $div);
    print "<div>\n";
    for ($j = 0; $j<$div;$j++) {
        print $sr[$j]."\n";
    }
    print "</div>";
}

?>
```

Если же нужно разбивать на группы 2 1 2 1 и так далее, то тут чуточку сложнее

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); #собственно массив
$len = count($a); # запомним размер массива
$div = 3; # по сколько разбивать
$div1 = 2; # размер первой группы
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i+=$div) {
    $sr = array_slice($a, $i, $div);
    $q = count($sr);
    print "<div>\n";
    for ($j = 0; $j < min($q,$div1); $j++) {
        print $sr[$j]."\n";
    }
    print "</div>\n";

    if ($q > $div1) {
        print "<div>\n";
        for ($j = $div1; $j < min($div, $q); $j++) {
            print $sr[$j]."\n";
        }
        print "</div>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Воспользовался вариантом  на группы 2 1 2 1, всё классно работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Простенький и визуальный пример

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
    if($key % 3 == 0)
    {
        echo '<div style="width: 500px; background: #e5e5e5; clear: both;">'.$val.'</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div style="float: left; background: #3d3d3d; width: 250px;">'.$val.'</div>';
    }
}
```